# Default settings for iPhone - How to find?

Tags: iphone, sorting, settings, contacts, default

I want to know the default settings for iPhone contacts app's..

- sorting order
- display order

I'm having an iPhone but I'm not ensure about its current settings state. I may/maynot change the default settings in past.

Is there any official Apple website available that provides all the default settings of iPhone/iPad/iPod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 99% sure I never changed this setting on my iPhone, so here are my current settings which should also be the default settings:

Sort order: Last, First
Display order: First, Last

Comment: I'm worrying about that 1% :) Anyway thanks.. Do you know any official website for this?

Comment: At last, I lost my all settings to find the default setting. :( Now I believe that you never changed your mobile settings :) Thanks